# Prolog mystery(c,[a,b,c,d],Z)

Tags: prolog

I think the answer is 3 but I am not sure, can anyone provide some help?

Suppose the following two statements are entered into Prolog:

```
mystery(X,[X|L],L).
mystery(X,[Y|L],[Y|M])  :-  mystery(X,L,M).
```

What would Prolog return if one then gives it the following goal?

```
?- mystery(c,[a,b,c,d],Z).
```

Comment: Did you try to run it? What did you see?

Comment: Also, how can the answer be "3"? Three banana's?

Answer (score 6):

So, `mystery/3` is defined as:

```
mystery(X, [X|L], L).
mystery(X, [Y|L], [Y|M]) :- mystery(X, L, M).
```

**There are (at least) three ways to look at `mystery`:**

1. It takes an element `X` (first parameter), looks for its existence in a given list (second parameter) and returns that same list, minus *one* occurrence of `X` (third parameter). Thus:

   ```
   ?- mystery(c, [a, b, c, d], Z).
   Z = [a, b, d] ;
   fail.

   ?- mystery(c, [a, b, c, d, c], Z).
   Z = [a, b, d, c] ;
   Z = [a, b, c, d] ;
   fail.
   ```
2. Another way to look at `mystery` is that it checks whether the lists constituting its second and third argument only differ with respect to one element, i.e. that the second list equals the third list, except that it has one additional element in one place. Thus:

   ```
   ?- mystery(X, [a, b, c, d], [a, b]).
   fail.

   ?- mystery(X, [a, b, c, d], [a, b, c]).
   X = d ;
   fail.
   ```

   Note that order is important:

   ```
   ?- mystery(X, [a, b, c, d], [a, c, b]).
   fail.
   ```
3. Lastly, `mystery` can also generate all ways in which the first argument can be interspersed in the list of the third argument. Thus:

   ```
   ?- mystery(d, Y, [a, b, c]).
   Y = [d, a, b, c] ;
   Y = [a, d, b, c] ;
   Y = [a, b, d, c] ;
   Y = [a, b, c, d] ;
   fail.
   ```

Comment: A fourth way of looking at it, is a variant of 1 and 2. The second argument has, by itself, all information needed. This makes `mystery/3` simply a way of picking an element from a list. Try asking `?- mystery(X, [a, b, c, d], L).`